# Format on Shopify them doesn't match development after pushing

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I duplicated and modified an existing theme. I pulled the theme files using the CLI, edited the theme using VS code and checked the results. I then push the theme to as follows:

Shopify CLI version is 3.47.5

Theme Section store_logos code:

```
{% stylesheet %}
    .debug {
        outline:solid 1px blue;
    }
    .center-block {
        display: block;
        margin-inline: auto;
        width: max-content;
        max-width: 96%;
    }
    .logoHolder {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        gap: clamp(20px, 5vw, 50px); 
        margin-bottom:50px;
        margin-inline:auto;
        width: 70%;
    }
    .title {
        font-size: clamp( 12px, 5vw, 48px) !important;
        margin-bottom: 80px !important;
        text-align: center;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
           
    }

{% endstylesheet %}


<div class="col-lg-12 ">
    <h2 class="center-block title">
        {% case section.settings.font_case %}
            {% when 'capitalize' %}
                {{ section.settings.title | capitalize }}
            {% when 'upcase' %}
                {{ section.settings.title | upcase }}
            {% when 'downcase' %}
                {{ section.settings.title | downcase }}
            {% else %}
                {{ section.settings.title | upcase }}
        {% endcase %}
    </h2>
    <div class="logoHolder">
        {% for logo in section.blocks %}
            {{ logo.settings.logo | img_url: logo.settings.logo_size | img_tag }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% schema %}
    {
        "name": "Store Logos Section",
        "class": "store-logos",
        "settings": [
            {
                "id": "title",
                "type" : "text",
                "label" : "Store logos title",
                "default" : "Find our rice at these great stores"
            },
            {
                "id": "font_case",
                "type": "select",
                "label": "Font Case",
                "options": [
                    { "value": "upcase", "label": "Upper Case"},
                    { "value": "capitalize", "label": "Capitalize"},
                    { "value": "downcase", "label": "Lower Case"}
                ],
                "default": "capitalize"
            }
        ],
        "blocks":[
            {
                "name": "store logos",
                "type": "store_logos",
                "settings": [
                    {
                        "id":"logo",
                        "type":"image_picker",
                        "label":"Logo"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "logo_size",
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "Logo Size",
                        "default": "200x"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "store",
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "Store Name"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
{% endschema %}
```

page template

```
<div id='scasl-app-container' class="new-for-mobile" style="display:none">
  <div class="bh-sl-container scasl-container" style="margin-top:150px" >
      {% section 'store_logos' %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Image of section from development
[image of section from development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYtFG.png)

Image of section after push from Shopify:
[Section after pushing to shopify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8OJL.png)

Why is the theme that was pushed to shopify displaying differently than the theme in development?

I compared the code in Shopify with the code in development. The two are identical.
I tried pushing the file a second time with not change.

I expected the pushed theme and the development theme to display the same.